How to create a custom component that can contain other components inside when using?
I'm new to React Native and want to create a custom container component that can be reused to contain other components. Here is the container:
const BaseView = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

Here is how I want to use it:
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BaseView>
      <Text>Hello World</Text>
    </BaseView>
  );
}

But when using it, BaseView shows an issue: Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. So how should I modify this? Should I use props?

According to this link props should contain a children property

You need to specify that <BaseView/> takes a children prop in your component definition:
const BaseView = ({children}:{children:ReactNode}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
        {children}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

